# Jetty 9.2 configure ssl in module

Tags: java, jetty, keytool, jetty-9

up untill now I had ssl configured on my jetty like this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/jetty/etc/keystore/jetty/jetty.jks                           
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/jetty/etc/keystore/jetty/cacerts.myown
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=myPass
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=myPass
```

in this was the password is in plain text, so I am trying to do as in this documentation:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/configuring-security.html#jetty-home-and-jetty-base
So I added a ssl.ini to start.d with this lines

```
--module=https
--module=ssl
jetty.secure.port=8443
jetty.keystore=etc/keystore/jetty/jetty.jks
jetty.truststore=etc/keystore/jetty/cacerts.myown
jetty.keystore.password=OBF:1vn21ugu1saj1dsadsad213ewqqwgw1vo0
jetty.truststore.password=OBF:1vn21ugu1saj1dsadsad213ewqqwgw1vo0
jetty.keymanager.password=OBF:1vn21ugu1saj1dsadsad213ewqqwgw1vo0
```

and I removed the -Djavax....
but it look like jetty is not loading my key and sruststore,
from the log I can see that the default cacerts of java is loading
and no key is loaded what am I missing,

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Program Files (x86)\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
```

Comment: check jetty-ssl enabled in start.ini

Comment: I have it in my ssl.ini
--module=https
--module=ssl
both of them is there something else I am missing ?

Comment: Run the following and report back (in your question): `$ cd /path/to/mybase && java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config`